# How can use multi "if" in one tag

Tags: php, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

How can I use multi "if" in one tag `like <header>`.
each `div` related to a tab. so I want to make a condition for each tab, for showing.

```html
<?php     
$mainbox = get_field('on');
$guide = get_field('install_guide');
$required = get_field('required');
?>
<section class="fieldset"> 
<header>
<?php
if (!empty($mainbox)){
<div class="download-taber active"> tab1</div> //// if true show this otherwise hide it
<div class="attr-taber">tab2</div>} //// if true show this otherwise hide it

elseif (!empty($guide)){ 
<div class="install-guide-taber">tab3</div>} //// if true show this otherwise hide it

elseif (!empty($required)){
  <div class="system-required-taber">tab4</div>} //// if true show this otherwise hide it
?>  
</header>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you are not closing your condition tag properly. it should be like this
`<?php
if (!empty($mainbox)){ ?>
<div class="download-taber active"> tab1</div> //// if true show this otherwise hide it
<div class="attr-taber">tab2</div> <?php } ?>`

Comment: I don't think you need SO to add closing and opening php tags :-)

Comment: You shouldn't use `elseif`otherwise only the first tab whichs condition is true is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply (list statement there for ease of swapping values for testing):

```
<?php                   
list($mainbox, $guide, $required)  = [true, true, true];
?>
<section class="fieldset">  
    <header>
    <?php if($mainbox) { ?>
        <div class="download-taber active">tab1</div>
        <div class="attr-taber">tab2</div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($guide) { ?>
        <div class="install-guide-taber">tab3</div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($required) { ?>
        <div class="system-required-taber">tab4</div>
    <?php } ?>      
    </header>
</section>
```

If all variables are set to true, all tabs will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

To embade html in PHP you have to keep your html code in the echo tag of php
 try this.

```
 <?php                  
    $mainbox = get_field('on');
    $guide = get_field('install_guide');
    $required = get_field('required');
    ?>
    <section class="fieldset">  
    <header>
    <?php
    if (!empty($mainbox)){
    echo "<div class='download-taber active'>tab1</div>"; //// if true show this otherwise hide it
    echo "<div class='attr-taber'>tab2</div>";} //// if true show this otherwise hide it

    elseif (!empty($guide)){    
    echo "<div class='install-guide-taber'>tab3</div>";} //// if true show this otherwise hide it

    elseif (!empty($required)){
            echo "<div class='system-required-taber'>tab4</div>";} //// if true show this otherwise hide it
    ?>      
    </header>
    </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```